# Revoke Access granted to my application Fitbit API - Fitbit 409 Conflict

Tags: fitbit

My app lets users register themselves and then via FitBit oAuth, authenticate themselves using FitBit. This will give me a Auth Token and Token Secret.

I want to revoke access to my application via Fitbit API in code. Currently, I have used RemoveSubscriptions() API call, but its is not revoking access.
Is there any way by which I can revoke access to my application from Fitbit API? I want to completely remove all the associated subscriptions and revoke them access to application.

On Fitbit site, there is an option - Go to Settings -> Applications -> Revoke Access button.  But, I want to revoke access in my application code. If i don't revoke access, it will throw a "FitbitException - Error -409 Conflict" because the same subscription is used by some other account of my application.